# cookie 選択画面が消えない

Tags: バグ, 完了

今週に入ったころから cookie 選択ダイアログが英語表示となっており、なおかつ選択肢を選んでも消えないというか、画面内リンクをたどると再度 cookie 選択ダイアログが表示されています。

おま環なのか確認したいところです。
当方 Windows 10 x64 + Chrome x64 Ver 120.0.6099.225 で、シークレットウィンドウで閲覧しております。

ちなみに本家 `www.stackoverflow.com` のほうは同一 UA にて問題なく動作しているように見えます。なおかつ、一度 `www.stackoverflow.com` を閲覧して cookie 選択ダイアログにて選択を行うと `ja.stackoverflow.com` 側にも選択結果が反映されているように見えます。

Comment: ロシア語版等でも再現するので、MSE にもバグ報告しておきました。 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/396179

Comment: 今日 2024/Feb/07 あたりから挙動が変わりましたね・・・直ったというか要らん動きしているというか。別議題立てたほうがよさそうな気がしてきた。

Comment: 自分が改めて試した限りでは、日本語では表示されるものの、traducir での翻訳とは若干違う＆日本語以外の多言語サイトにアクセスした場合もなぜか日本語のダイアログで表示される状態ですね。一応 MSE の方ではバグとして認識してくれているみたいなので、このまま様子見でもいいのかなと思います。

Comment: とりあえず様子見に強く同意。一応まとめておくと、今日この時点での問題点は１．本家英語サイトを訪問しても Cookie Dialog はなぜか日本語。それは仕様として正しいか否か。２．文言「すべて拒否する」はミスリーディングであろう。３．英語サイトと日本語サイトの Cookie 選択結果が連動すべきか否か。４．一部サイトで cookie 選択ダイアログすら出ない (`es.stackoverflow.com` だと、ウチでは出ない）どれも仕様というか方針レベルの話なので、オイラたち一般ユーザーがブーブー言っても仕方ない感がひしひしとします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ご報告ありがとうござました！繰り返し表示される問題および翻訳が修正されました。もし同様の状況が再び発生した場合にはどうぞお知らせくださいませ。

Comment: 2024/Feb/19 08:00JST の時点でのまとめ。 `es.stackoverflow.com` や `ru.stackoverflow.com` の cookie 選択ダイアログは UA によらずに現地語になっていることは確認。 `stackoverflow.com` の cookie 選択ダイアログは依然として日本語を確認。翻訳の文言「すべて拒否する」は、すべての cookie すなわち「ログイン cookie すら拒否する」と読めるのでミスリーディングなのは変化なし。他は運営方針レベルの話なのでこの場で話題にしても仕方ないだろうと指摘してこの議題は解決としておきます。

Comment: @774RR ボタンが「すべて拒否する」になっているのは、翻訳の問題では無さそうです。
「Necessary cookies only」の翻訳は[用意されています](https://ja.traducir.win/strings/17117)
この問題は[Meta Stack Exchangeに報告しました](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/396907/348970)。